# Check sqlite database is open or closed in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have two methods in my `DBDriver` class to `open` and `close` `sqlite database` as below.

```
private SQLiteDatabase database;

/**
     * Open Database to read and write.
     * 
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public void open() throws SQLException {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    }

    /**
     * Close opened database.
     */
    public void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
    }
```

I'm using above methods in my other class to open and close `sqlite database`.

I want to identify database is open or closed. How could I do this?

Comment: dont know why you want to check for the database open or close. but it is used whenever you want to fetch/access the data from the database. Before going to fetch the data you must have to open database in the read/write permission and after using data you must have to close it. Hope you got the point if you want, how to use the open and close the database.

Comment: @iDroidExplorer i need to add a condition in my app. for it i want to identify database is open or closed.

Comment: ok then you go with justDanyul's answer in your post. it is right one to help you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `isOpen()` to check, so in your case, that would be

```
database.isOpen()
```

just a tip, when working with Java based API (or any APIs for that matter), learning to use the documentation of the API is key. The docs will tell you which methods are available for any given class. For example, you got a instance of the class SQLiteDatabase. Checking the javadocs below

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

its pretty trivial to identify the method you are looking for.

Comment: Ho do you do this in Typescript?  I get:  `ERROR in ./app/pages/chats/chatsStorageService.ts
(37,56): error TS2339: Property 'isOpen' does not exist on type 'SQLite'.`